# Failed to Build React-Native-Unity-View with error "finished with non-zero exit value 255"

Tags: android, react-native, unity-game-engine

So, I work on react-native project and wanted to merge my react-native with unity project. I use `@asmadsen/react-native-unity-view`[>here](https://github.com/asmadsen/react-native-unity-view). But, everytime I build I got this error:

> Task :UnityExport:BuildIl2CppTask FAILED FAILURE: Build failed with an
> exception.
>
> Where: Build file '/Users/rahamirez.ga/Documents/Projects/chacha/kidrn/android/UnityExport/build.gradle'
> line: 62
>
> What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':UnityExport:BuildIl2CppTask'.  Process 'command
> '/Users/rahamirez.ga/Documents/Projects/chacha/kidrn/android/UnityExport/src/main/Il2CppOutputProject/IL2CPP/build/deploy/netcoreapp3.1/il2cpp''
> finished with non-zero exit value 255

this is what my Unity Export `build.gradle` look like:

```
allprojects {
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            google()
        }
    }
}

// GENERATED BY UNITY. REMOVE THIS COMMENT TO PREVENT OVERWRITING WHEN EXPORTING AGAIN

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'


dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.ar:core:1.22.0'
    implementation ':unity-classes'
    implementation(name: 'VuforiaEngine', ext:'aar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
    buildToolsVersion '30.0.2'

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 31
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
        }
        versionCode 1
        versionName '0.1'
        consumerProguardFiles 'proguard-unity.txt'
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    aaptOptions {
        noCompress = ['.ress', '.resource', '.obb'] + unityStreamingAssets.tokenize(', ')
        ignoreAssetsPattern = "!.svn:!.git:!.ds_store:!*.scc:.*:!CVS:!thumbs.db:!picasa.ini:!*~"
    }

    packagingOptions {
        doNotStrip '*/armeabi-v7a/*.so'
        doNotStrip '*/arm64-v8a/*.so'
    }
}

def getSdkDir() {
    Properties local = new Properties()
    local.load(new FileInputStream("${rootDir}/local.properties"))
    return local.getProperty('sdk.dir')
}

def BuildIl2Cpp(String workingDir, String targetDirectory, String architecture, String abi, String configuration) {
    exec {
        commandLine(workingDir + "/src/main/Il2CppOutputProject/IL2CPP/build/deploy/netcoreapp3.1/il2cpp",
            "--compile-cpp",
            "--libil2cpp-static",
            "--platform=Android",
            "--architecture=" + architecture,
            "--configuration=" + configuration,
            "--outputpath=" + workingDir + targetDirectory + abi + "/libil2cpp.so",
            "--cachedirectory=" + workingDir + "/build/il2cpp_"+ abi + "_" + configuration + "/il2cpp_cache",
            "--additional-include-directories=" + workingDir + "/src/main/Il2CppOutputProject/IL2CPP/external/bdwgc/include",
            "--additional-include-directories=" + workingDir + "/src/main/Il2CppOutputProject/IL2CPP/libil2cpp/include",
            "--tool-chain-path=" + android.ndkDirectory,
            "--map-file-parser=" + workingDir + "/src/main/Il2CppOutputProject/IL2CPP/MapFileParser/MapFileParser.exe",
            "--generatedcppdir=" + workingDir + "/src/main/Il2CppOutputProject/Source/il2cppOutput",
            "--baselib-directory=" + workingDir + "/src/main/jniStaticLibs/" + abi,
            "--dotnetprofile=unityaot")
        environment "ANDROID_SDK_ROOT", getSdkDir()
    }
    delete workingDir + targetDirectory + abi + "/libil2cpp.sym.so"
    ant.move(file: workingDir + targetDirectory + abi + "/libil2cpp.dbg.so", tofile: workingDir + "/symbols/" + abi + "/libil2cpp.so")
}

android {
    task BuildIl2CppTask {
        doLast {
              BuildIl2Cpp(projectDir.toString().replaceAll('\\\\', '/'), '/src/main/jniLibs/', 'ARMv7', 'armeabi-v7a', 'Release');
              BuildIl2Cpp(projectDir.toString().replaceAll('\\\\', '/'), '/src/main/jniLibs/', 'ARM64', 'arm64-v8a', 'Release');
        }
    }
    afterEvaluate {
        if (project(':UnityExport').tasks.findByName('mergeDebugJniLibFolders'))
            project(':UnityExport').mergeDebugJniLibFolders.dependsOn BuildIl2CppTask
        if (project(':UnityExport').tasks.findByName('mergeReleaseJniLibFolders'))
            project(':UnityExport').mergeReleaseJniLibFolders.dependsOn BuildIl2CppTask
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            jni.srcDirs = ["src/main/Il2CppOutputProject"]
        }
    }
}
```

I use macbook air m1 macOS big sur. I'm so stuck, any idea what is the problem here? Thank You!

Comment: Do you have any success building with Android Studio directly ?

Comment: Same problem here...